# SQL WHERE clause with concatenation

Tags: php, mysql

Company IDs in table2 end in '9999', e.g., 12349999.  I want to match these with company IDs in table1, which don't end in '9999', e.g. 1234.

I am trying to write a sql query in my php script that does something like this:

```
WHERE table1.company_IDs=table2.company_IDs.'9999'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: MySQL function `CONCAT` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
WHERE table1.company_IDs = CONCAT(table2.company_IDs, '9999')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your ID's are stored as INTEGERS, you could just do:

```
WHERE table2.company=table1.company*10000+9999
```

If your ID's are stored as strings, use `CONCAT`:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat